# AngularJS service ok but no data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

i'm developing a webapp in AngularJS. I've created a service for send json requests and receive json data via post. The service is ok because when i load the page Firebug shows me json's data, but the view doesn't load data.

This is my code

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.service('selectSrv',['$http', function($http){
        this.select = function(tab, fields){
                $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                return $http.post('/loader',{posttab:tab, postfields:fields})
                        .success(function(data){
                            return data;    });
            };
    }]);
    app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/report",{
                          templateUrl:"/reportV.html",
                          controller:"reportController",
                          resolve:{
                                   dati: function(selectSrv){
                                       return selectSrv.select(table,["col1","        };
}]);
col2","col3"]); }
                          }   })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
```

this is my reportController.js

```
app.controller("reportController", ['$scope','$log', function($scope, $log, dati){
    $scope.rows = dati;    }]);
```

and this is my reportV.html

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <tr>
                <td>{{row.code}}</td>
                <td>{{row.surname}}</td>
                <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

also, if i write to log i see "undefined" instead see data on log.

Regards to all.

Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare resolved dependency in your array notation. Should be:

```
app.controller("reportController", ['$scope', '$log', 'dati', function($scope, $log, dati) {
    $scope.rows = dati;               // note this DI --^   
}]);
```

Comment: Ok, it works. I don't know that is necessary filter dati.data
Enjoy

Comment: `data` is necessarry because $http service returns response object with bunch of stuff so it needs to wrap actual response data into something, so it declares `data` property. In your case, instead of `success` use `.then(function(response) { return response.data; })`. And remember to accept the answer if it helps :).